# My console log is reading undefined even tough the value has been set in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a pollingapp in which I wanted to implement unique nicknames so in the `<script>` part. I have this data function which contains some parameter which I have been having no trouble calling except for one I have this leaderboard object which is simply: `leaderBoard:{nicknames:[], scores:[]},`

I have then in the created part made a

```
socket.on("nickNames", function(nicknames){
  this.leaderBoard.nicknames = nicknames;
}
```

Or well that's the gist of it my console is then telling me that

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nicknames')"

And I have no idea how to fix it and I have checked that nicknames is defined and everything seems to be working okay except for this.

EDIT: apparently when using a function like above this is not actually refering to the data objects the soloutin was to instead use something called a gamma function? which instead of function(nicknames){code} should look like (nicknames) =>{code}

Comment: Probably `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: but shouldnt this refer to my data objects? this seems to be working correctly in all my ordinary methods ex   `methods:{ setNick: function() {socket.emit("setNick",this.nickname)}}`

Comment: `this` will will have whatever value Socket.IO gives it when it gets called.

Comment: yes thanks i just realized this, thank you for pointing me in the right direction